Loading JSON into Dataverse with Unique Key issue
I'm generating an export file of a table (which I can't connect directly through API's). I'm trying to load this JSON file into a Dataverse Table. I have identified the uniqueKey in my dataflow and then in my table as well. However, when I load my table once more it duplicates all the records and doesn't replace the values.
Can somebody help?
Cheers

How are you loading the JSON file into dataverse table? What method are you using? is it dataflow?
Are you sure you have included the table id (uniqueKey) in the final dataset before loading/importing?

Loading the JSON file via a dataflow, my first steps in the dataflow is expanding the JSON table 2-3 times. After expanding my uniquekey is available in the dataflow.
